# Derive encryption private key from Windows Credentials

Tags: windows, encryption

I am looking for a good idea how to derive a private key from the Windows Credentials of a logged on user.

I want to encrypt data from the user in a secure way and store it on an external system. The user should be able to connect from different Windows clients.

It should not be required for the user to enter a passphrase on every access - I want to replace the passphrase with the Windows Credentials.

The application reading / writing the encrypted information should be written in .NET, could be a Desktop application. But I think the question itself is independent from a specific programming language.

I already did a bit of research, but I am missing pointers into the right direction what to look for.

I have an Active Directory available - could this be of any help? Are there private keys available somewhere in it that I could reuse?

Anybody did a similar thing?

Comment: You know Windows's Encrypting File System (EFS)?

Comment: Do you mean private key as in RSA or a secret key as in AES? The former will be a bit hard.

Comment: Yes, I know EFS. It won't fit here, because one of the possible platforms would be a SharePoint team site.

A symmetrical key as in AES would work for my purposes as I just want to encrypt / decrypt the information with the user's credentials.